# Angular.js $http intercept "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, interceptor

I'm trying to write a generic error handler for my website using `$http'`s interceptors but they don't seem to be able to do what I want to do.

I placed interceptors on `'response'` and `'responseError'` but they never get called when the server is offline/not reponding (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). I understand why this happens, there's no response to intercept.

I'd like to know if there's a generic way of catching these errors, other than listening to the `$httpPromise`'s `error` callback for each request.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can probably check the status of the ResponseError. When an API is offline that is 0 (until Angular 1.3.18) or -1 (since Angular 1.3.19):

```
angular.module("services.interceptor", arguments).config(function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
          responseError: function(rejection) {
                if(rejection.status <= 0) {
                    window.location = "noresponse.html";
                    return;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work. I thought I tried listening to `responseError` but clearly, there's something I didn't do right.

Comment: Is there a way to handle such errors after the "config time" or when the $scope is available? In order to show errors using a controller. Maybe it's the wrong way to show net errors but i can't find a proper way...

Comment: Yes, you can inject `$injector` and transit to some state. For example:
```
angular.module('module').factory('accessHttpInterceptor', [
  '$injector',
  function(
    $injector
  ) {
    return {
      responseError: function accessHttpInterceptorResponseError (rejection) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        $state.go('offline');
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: This Answer helped with the $q definition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171986/angularjs-httpprovider-interceptor-documentation